# Making a view in layout keep its size when another grows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I want to achieve a simple layout like this one:

|TITLE | DATE              |

Both views should wrap to its contents and should be aligned to the left side. Title should grow to the right and ellipsize at the end if it content does not fit in one single line. Date should be to the right side of title and keep it width without ellipsize it when title is large and date is moved until the right side.

I'm not able to achieve the second requirement. Date is always ellipsized when title grows and date reach the right side of the screen. I have tried with LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout.

Could anyone give me an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i get your question but you can simply use `LinearLayout` with `weight`. **eg:-**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5" // or whatever you want
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="TITLE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5" // or whatever you want
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Date" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That will divide the horizontal space in two fixed portions, and I dont want that.